# Get Aptana to recognize php if it is saved as an html file

Tags: php, configuration, aptana3

I'm working on this project that uses a lot of php files saved as html files. I can't really change the filetypes so please don't suggest that. [image]

Is there a way that I can configure Aptana Studios to recognize php in html files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the file in the Project Explorer. Then choose Open With -> Other ... -> PHP Source Editor

Or if you want a more permanent solution. Go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations, then select *.html and add the PHP Source Editor and make it the default.